# Cascading(buffer) implementation

Tags: cascading

I need to create a buffer in cascading hadoop.

Suppose i have fields :

> member_id,amountpaid,diadnosis_id,diagnosis_description,superGrouper_id,superGrouper_descriptiion,grouperId,grouperDescription

I need to

1. group the fields from `member_id` and `superGrouper_id`
2. send these information using every pipe to a buffer
3. the buffer output should be :`member_id`, highest paid sorting from `superGrouper`, highest paid sorting from `grouperId`, highest paid from `diagnosis_id`, along with their description...

Please help me creating a buffer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: noone can solve this problem..:(

Comment: Could you post the input and output you expect. Then, I would try to provide you answer. Actually its not quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom buffer. Use the built in Max aggregator from Cascading. [Cascading Docs](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/operation/aggregator/Max.html)

You then just need to run the Max after a GroupBy.

```
pipe = new GroupBy(pipe, new Fields("member_id", "superGrouper_id");
pipe = new Every(pipe, new Fields("amountpaid"), new Max(new Fields("max_paid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
pipe = new GroupBy(pipe, new Fields("member_id", "superGrouper_id"), new Fields("superGrouper", "grouperId", "")); 
pipe = new Every(pipe, FirstNBuffer(int n));
```

I am sorry if I am wrong. Your question is not quite clear.